# Why is there a 'move zero,ra' at the entry of a MIPS program?

Tags: mips

I used a cross compiler mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc to compile a hello-world C program, and disassembled it with mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu-objdump, and get the following:

```
00400d00 <__start>:
  400d00:   03e00021        move    zero,ra
  400d04:   04110001        bal     400d0c <__start+0xc>
  400d08:   00000000        nop
  400d0c:   3c1c004b        lui     gp,0x4b
  400d10:   279c2010        addiu   gp,gp,8208
  400d14:   0000f821        move    ra,zero
  400d18:   8f848018        lw      a0,-32744(gp)
  400d1c:   8fa50000        lw      a1,0(sp)
  400d20:   27a60004        addiu   a2,sp,4
  400d24:   2401fff8        li      at,-8
  400d28:   03a1e824        and     sp,sp,at
  400d2c:   27bdffe0        addiu   sp,sp,-32
  400d30:   8f87801c        lw      a3,-32740(gp)
  400d34:   8f888020        lw      t0,-32736(gp)
  400d38:   00000000        nop
  400d3c:   afa80010        sw      t0,16(sp)
  400d40:   afa20014        sw      v0,20(sp)
  400d44:   afbd0018        sw      sp,24(sp)
  400d48:   8f998024        lw      t9,-32732(gp)
  400d4c:   00000000        nop
  400d50:   04110097        bal     400fb0 <__libc_start_main>
  400d54:   00000000        nop
```

The first instruction is 0x03e00021, and I translate it as opcode=0,rs=31,rt=0,rd=0,shamt=0,funct=33, so it is `addu $0, $31, $0`, writing to register $0, which is always zero. Why is there such a weird instruction?

Comment: I looked at a few MIPS executables compiled with mipsel-linux-uclibc-gcc and did not see that instruction anywhere in the dissassembly.

Comment: I've checked the code, the code comes from glibc.